# How to get discord.py bot to DM a specific user

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have searched around a lot for this answer, and I haven't found it. I want to use a suggestion command, that whenever someone uses it to suggest an idea, it DMs me, and me only.

Comment: Welcome at [so]. It is expected that questions meet certain criteria. These are described in the [ask] page that I strongly suggest you read. In addition we expect a certain level of effort to already have been spent on your part. This is typically done by showing us the code that you're working on and providing us with descriptions of the things you've tried and the results you've observed. In case of larger blocks of code, simplifying it to a [mcve] helps to understand the issue much quicker on our part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use the [`send_message`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_message) method. Prior to that, you have to find which `User` correspond to yourself.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # can be cached...
    me = await client.get_user_info('MY_SNOWFLAKE_ID')
    await client.send_message(me, "Hello!")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("#whatever you want it to be")
        await client.send_message(message.author, "#The message")
```

Replace the hashtagged things with the words that you want it to be. eg.: #whatever you want it to be could be "!help". #The message could be "The commands are...".

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Replace the hashtagged things with the words that you want it to be.
eg.: #whatever you want it to be could be "!help". #The message could be "The commands are..."

Answer (score 1):

For anyone new:

**Format:**

```
dmuser = await bot.fetch_user('user id as int')
await dmuser.send("This is a test!")
```

**on_message:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    dmuser = await bot.fetch_user(message.author.id)
    await dmuser.send("This is a test!")
```

**Commands Example 1:**

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    dmuser = await bot.fetch_user(ctx.author.id)
    await dmuser.send("This is a test!")
```

**Command Example 2:**

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, user:discord.Member):
    dmuser = await bot.fetch_user(user.id)
    await dmuser.send("This is a test!")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### discord.py v1.0.0+

Since v1.0.0 it's no longer `client.send_message` to send a message, instead you use `send()` of [`abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) which implements the following:

- [`discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [`discord.DMChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.DMChannel)
- [`discord.GroupChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.GroupChannel)
- [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User)
- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member)
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)

##### Example

**With `bot.command()` (recommended):**

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, text: str):
    me = bot.get_user(YOUR_ID)
    await me.send(text)  # or whatever you want to send here
```

**With `on_message`:**

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):

    if message.content.startswith("!suggest"):
        text = message.content.replace("!suggest", "")
        me = bot.get_user(YOUR_ID)
        await me.send(text)  # or whatever you want to send here
```