# Why can't I find client.send_message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that DMs the user who used a slash command. For some reason, I get an error:
`AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'`

I can't find any examples of **slash** commands that DM users.

```
# setup
import discord
import interactions

bot = interactions.Client(token="TOKEN")
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# gen command

@bot.command(
name="gen",
description="Generate a username and password.",
)
async def gen(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
print("test")
await client.send_message(interactions.user.id, "Hello!")

bot.start()
```

I would have expected this to DM the user who sent the command the string "Hello!"
Instead, only when I run the command, I get the error, `AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'`

Comment: The command is usually `send`.  Where did you read about `send_message`?

Comment: I found send_message in the link below. Replacing `send_message` with `send` I get a similar error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500214/how-to-get-discord-py-bot-to-dm-a-specific-user

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that was removed in Discord v1.0.0.  You have to use `send()` on the User or Member object.

Comment: You might want to look at [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) since this is a pretty standard function

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
member = client.get_user(int(interactions.user.id))
await member.send(“Hello!”)
```

You have to find the member using the id of the person who used the interaction to send then a message. Hope this helped.